# Spark Streaming with Kafka - Not all Kafka messages are received

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, azure-hdinsight

I'm working with Spark Streaming with Kafka for the first time have been facing the following issue:

I'm using the receiver-based approach for Kafka integration with Spark Streaming as:

`val kafkaConf = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "ip1:9042,ip2:9042", "group.id" -> "raw-email-event-streaming-consumer", "zookeeper.connect" -> "ip1:2181,ip2:2181")`

```
`val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaConf, Map(RN_MAIL_TOPIC -> RN_MAIL_TOPIC_PARTITIONS), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)`
```

I have found that a lot of messages from a Kafka topic are not received in the Spark Streaming job (~5k messages out of 7k messages produced aren't received). Please provide insights as to why this might be happening. I submit my streaming job to an Azure HDInsights cluster in a standalone mode currently, as follows:

`spark-submit --class <class_name> --master local[*] --deploy-mode client <executable>.jar`

Comment: does your topics have partitions?If yes..In receiver based approach spark does not handle the polling of multiple partitions from kafka topic under the hood.It has to be handled by the programmer.In direct approach its handled by Spark

Comment: Thanks, Kiran. I was indeed not able to read all partitions, was able to solve it.